# Which app is using Android Gps Engine

Tags: java, android, mobile, geolocation, gps

Am developing an Android application that will run in the background to see if the GPS is on. If the GPS is on it will then check if there is an application using the GPS. If there is no application using the GPS it should tell with a dialog. I was able to check if GPS is on or not MY CURRENT PROBLEM IS HOW DO I CHECK PROGRAMMATICALLY IF AN APPLICATION IS USING THE GPS. Code samples will be very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to check other application is using gps?. Your application can use gps even others app uses gps simultaneously. Although u can check the permission of others app physically and find out which app is using the gps in device setting . If this not solve your problem please elaborate your question.

Comment: Sometimes apps that uses GPS leaves the GPS on even after the app is closed. So my app is to periodically check if the GPS is in use by any app. If not it will automatically close the GPS.

Comment: you can turn off GPS on screen lock  or at a particular event. Use service class of android and check GPS  on screen lock , & if on then disable it. There r different way to do it.

Comment: It seems you don't understand my question. I know how to switch off the GPS programmatically. What I need is to check if any app is using the GPS or not.